# Dbus using C API

Tags: dbus

I need  any proper guide to  DBUS library installation and example usign C API

what i'm finding is example codes when i try to run throws an error like dbus library or corresponding header file is missing

**OS:ubutnu14.04 LTS** 
**arch : x86_64**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My favorite DBus guide (using libdbus, which I assume is what you want) is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200929010538/https://leonardoce.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/dbus-tutorial-using-the-low-level-api/). This tutorial will not cover everything, but it covers the basics of making a program and compiling it with libdbus. tl;dr in order to compile with libdbus put `#include <dbus/dbus.h>` in your program and use `` gcc -o dbus -Wall dbus.c `pkg-config --cflags dbus-1` `pkg-config --libs dbus-1 `` to compile and link to the libs.

Comment: You can run `pkg-config` with the `--libs` and `--cflags` passed in one go: `pkg-config --cflags --libs dbus-1`

Comment: The link is no longer valid as the authors seem to have deleted it, do you have anything else?

Comment: @Atreyagaurav oh, yikes. looks like the archive still works https://web.archive.org/web/20200929010538/https://leonardoce.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/dbus-tutorial-using-the-low-level-api/

Comment: Thank you, it does seem to have good info. I was having hard time finding info. Might have to just jump into some codebases to see how they're using it.

Comment: Here is for posterity more parts of the tutorial. Part 2: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20210617030225/https://leonardoce.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/dbus-tutorial-part-2/
Part 3:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210617031239/https://leonardoce.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/dbus-tutorial-part-3/

What a nice tutorial, hats of to the writer.